# I need help having this quit the function?

Tags: java

I need help making this program quit when I type "quit". This is supposed to be a fraction calculator; right now I want to make a driver loop to continue the function to take input until the user types "quit" with any casing.

```
import java.util.*;

public class FractionCalculator {

   // useDelimiter or split method in string class
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Greeting();
      produceAnswer();
   }

   static String value1Str = "";
   static String value2Str = "";
   static char operator = ' ';

   public static void Greeting() {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);

      String userName;
      System.out.print("Hello Person, What is your first name: ");
      userName = kb.next();
      System.out.println("Hi " + userName + ", welcome to the great  mystical fraction calculator.");
   }   

   public static void produceAnswer() {
      Scanner kb = new Scanner (System.in);
      System.out.println("What is your input or type quit to leave?");
      String input = kb.nextLine();     
      boolean value1Done = false;
      boolean operatorDone = false;
      boolean value2Done = false;
      boolean correctFormat = false;

      for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {   
         System.out.println("The input of given string is: " +input.charAt(i));         

         if (input.charAt(i) != ' ' && value1Done == false) {
            value1Str += input.charAt(i);
         }
         else{
            value1Done = true;
         }  

         if (input.charAt(i) == '+' || input.charAt(i) == '-' ||   input.charAt(i) == '*' || input.charAt(i) == '/' && operatorDone == false && value1Done == true) {
            operator = input.charAt(i);
            operatorDone = true;
            i=i+1;
         } 

         if (input.charAt(i) != ' ' && value1Done == true && value2Done == false) {
            value2Str  += input.charAt(i);
         }      
         else {
            value2Done = false;
         }
         else if kb.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
            System.out.println("Why are you leaving? Comeback soon bby");
            quit = true;
            correctFormat = true;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you've determined that "quit" was entered, put a break statement in the if statement block:

```
  else if (kb.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
      System.out.println("Why are you leaving? Comeback soon bye");
      break;
  }
```

Comment: FractionCalculator.java:70: error: '(' expected
         else if kb.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
                ^
FractionCalculator.java:70: error: ')' expected
         else if kb.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
                                                   ^
FractionCalculator.java:70: error: 'else' without 'if'
         else if kb.next().equalsIgnoreCase("quit"){
         ^

Comment: sorry, typo.  I fixed the answer